# Limit 1 post by user in each custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I wrote a function to limit 1 post by user in each custom post types (I created 3 custom post types).

The problem is that my function limit 1 post for ALL users and not 1 post for each user.

Can I have some help please ? What can I add ?

```
$post_types_name = array('subject-imposed', 'subject-free', 'dissertation');

function limit_posts() {
    global $post_types_name;
    global $pagenow;

    foreach ($post_types_name as $post_type_name) {

        $count_post = wp_count_posts($post_type_name)->publish;

        $max_posts = 1; //the number of max published posts

        if($count_post >= $max_posts){

            if (! empty($pagenow) && ('post-new.php' === $pagenow && ( $_GET['post_type'] == $post_type_name)) || ! empty($pagenow) && ('edit.php' === $pagenow && ( $_GET['post_type'] == $post_type_name)) ){
                ?>
                <style>
                .editor-limit {
                    text-align: center;
                }
                </style>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(window).load(function() {
                    jQuery('.editor-styles-wrapper').html('<p class="editor-limit">You have reached the maximum number of posts.</p>');
                });
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('admin_head' , 'limit_posts');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using `wp_count_posts(` for counting posts, so it will return the number of posts.

If you want to get the number of posts for given user, you should use [`count_user_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/) instead.

So change this line:

```
$count_post = wp_count_posts($post_type_name)->publish;
```

to:

```
 $count_post = count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), $post_type_name, true );
```

Comment: Okay now I understand better. It works perfectly. Thank you for your help